# Hamachi not installed on Centos 7 when i follow this steps

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, hamachi

I'm trying to install Hamachi on Centos 7, i follow this documents but it was for Centos 5 ,6

[Install and Configure LogMeIN ( Hamachi ) on RHEL/CentOS 5/6](http://tecadmin.net/install-and-configure-logmein-hamachi-on-rhelcentos-56/)

Also the link of latest logmein-hamachi is not working, so i use latest version from this link

[LogMeIn Hamachi for Linux](https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux)

and download last version of hamachi by this command line

```
wget https://secure.logmein.com/labs/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.139-1.x86_64.rpm
```

And the file is successfully downloaded, but when i try to run this command to install hamachi

```
rpm -ivh logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.139-1.x86_64.rpm
```

it is not installed

Comment: What happens when you run the `rpm ...` command?  Is there any error message?  Does nothing happen?

Comment: i don't remember the error message, but it was mean that this package is not install

Comment: you'll need to rerun `rpm ...` and edit in the output into your Q. The problem could be many things, so please don't make us play "20 questions". Good luck.

Comment: the problem was i installed hamachi version 32, but when i uninstall it and install the package of the accepted answer, it fix the problem and working fine, thank you for you help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the yum software package manager to install rpm packages.
Try:

```
yum localinstall logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.139-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: this is the result  `Examining logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.139-1.x86_64.rpm: logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.139-1.x86_64
logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.139-1.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Nothing to do
`

Comment: i think this your package has fix this problem. i start hamachi by this code `/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi start` and working :D